# ERROR 147 - searching max record based on criteria

Tags: sql, compiler-errors

I am getting error message 147 when I run this query.  I am looking for all records where comment contains DBA and is NOT expired or expiration date is null, but I need to look at the most recent record with this criteria.  I am alsno not sure how to format hte dateto get current date in the format of '2013-09-18 00:00:00' so that the query can be run at anytime without have to hard code the date.  I also have MIN() in my select statements because it made me insery something there... is there something else I should use in place of that?

```
SELECT 
                AD.AccountNumber AS ACCOUNTNUMBER,
                MIN(AD.SharePrimeNameLongName) AS NAME,
                MIN(AD.SharePrimeNameSSN) AS SSN,
                MIN(AD.SharePrimeNameSSNType) AS SSNTYPE,
                MIN(C.COMMENT) AS COMMENT

    FROM    
                ARCU.ARCUShareDetailed AS AD  JOIN 
                COMMENT AS C ON 
                AD.AccountNumber = C.PARENTACCOUNT

    WHERE   
                AD.AccountStatus = 'OPEN' AND
                (C.ProcessDate = (Select MAX(AD.ProcessDate) from COMMENT having 
                C.COMMENT Like '%DBA')  AND
                ((C.EXPIRATIONDATE > '2013-09-18 00:00:00') OR 
                (C.EXPIRATIONDATE IS NULL)))

    ORDER BY AccountNumber
```

Comment: I don't remember coming across error numbers in the SQL standards... What flavor of SQL are you using, and is "147" the error message or is there something more meaningful?

Comment: Also, what is that `having C.COMMENT Like '%DBA'` supposed to do?

Comment: Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: hacing C.Comment Like '%DBA%' is going to pull any record where 'DBA' shows up in the comment... basically any account that is a DBA account which is shown by the comments... has to be the most recent comment though as they are continuously updated and records are created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Error 147 as a result of having the `AD.AccountNumber` in the select without it being in a `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause.

As for the date, if you want anything that is greater than today at midnight, you could just use `CONVERT(date, GETDATE())`

Comment: My mistake, it must be your `HAVING` clause in the subquery, having should only be used with an aggregate, just use `WHERE C.COMMENT like '%DBA'`

Comment: still getting the same error.  i feel like i've tried everything i can think of.. alhtough i'm new to this.. but i keep getting the same error every time i change something